# Cannot push with Jekyll

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I have created an empty array in Jekyll but I am not able to push data.
Here it is described how to do but it does not seem to work on my machine. I use Jekyll 2.5.3

```
            {% assign selected = site.array %}
            {% for success in site.data.success %}
                {% assign selected = selected | push: success.id %}
            {% endfor %}
```

site.array is defined into my _config.yml as

```
site.array: []
```

I am sure that success.id exists

**UPDATE 1**

I changed in _config.yml

```
array: []
```

Still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Why define a `site.something` in `_config.yml` ?

Any variable defined here will be accessed with the `site` prefix, but it's not up to you to add this prefix, Jekyll takes care of it. eg: `{{ site.title }}` refers to `site: My awesome title`. It's automatic.

Just define : `emptyArray: []`, and access it with `site.emptyArray`.

With `site.array: []`, you're defining a configuration variable that will never be `site.site.array` because a yaml key is supposed to be a string. Here, the only way to access your variable, is to write `site["site.array"]`.

Note: If you can, upgrade to a newer version of Jekyll if you want to be future-proof.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your answer. I've tried your solution but push is still not working. I also updated the question. Any other lead?

Comment: And `site.data.success` is ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if Jekyll accepts an empty array, "out of the blue".

So, try to use an `if` statement before the `for` loop:

```
{% if site.array %}
{% assign selected = site.array %} 
{% for success in site.data.success %} {% assign selected = selected | push: success.id %} 
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

And keep just `array:` in your `_config.yml`. Any variable defined in this file will be called by `site.variable`.

I suggest you to try with some values in the array before leaving it empty, to make sure the code works.

Hope to have helped!